# ImageMagick PHP additonal formats

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I need to convert RAW files (from cameras, like .arw, .cr2,...) to JPGs using PHP. According to https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php, they are all supported. Unfortunately, the installation on my server does not have them installed.
How can I add them? SSH access is available

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried google something like "how to install imagemagick on xxxx-server"? (replace xxxx with the OS your server is running)

Comment: You probably need to install `ufraw` package to read those.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a ImageMagick's [delegates.xml](https://www.imagemagick.org/source/delegates.xml). Usually located under `/usr/share/ImageMagick-X` on server. IM is capable of handing encode/decode task to other utilities. If your have administrative access to the server, it may be as simple as ....

```xml
<delegatemap>
   <delegate decode="arw" command=""ufraw-batch" --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 "--output=%u.png" "%i""/>
</delegatemap>
```

Although, the formats listed should be included as core formats. It's more than possible that such formats have been banned by `policy.xml`, or compiled without support for security reasons. Might be worth inquiring with server owner.